# Help Continue VBS String?

Tags: vbscript

I'm VERY new to VBScript and general computer programing in general.
IF I were to do this:

```
a=inputbox("Password:") 
if a="Drop Zero" then 
    msgbox"Loging On" 
else
    msgbox"Invalid"
end if 

a=inputbox("Hello, what would you like to know:")
```

I can't continue with the if and else after the second input box. Any help would be highly appreciated for a nOOb such as myself.!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm in trouble understanding your question.
Anyway, if you need to quit when password is wrong, you can try this:

```
a=inputbox("Password:") 
if a="Drop Zero" then 
    msgbox"Logging On" 
else
    msgbox"Invalid"
    WScript.Quit
end if 

a=inputbox("Hello, what would you like to know:")
```

**UPDATE:**
Look at this code taken from [here](http://forums.techguy.org/software-development/68970-vbscript-if-else-nested-statements.html):

```
Function ValidInteger(sNumber,iMin,iMax)

    If IsNumeric(sNumber) = 0 Then
        If InStr(sNumber,".") Then
            If CLng(sNumber)>= iMin And CLng(sNumber)<= iMax Then 
                ValidInteger=""
            Else
                ValidInteger = "You must enter a number between " & iMin & " and " & iMax
            End If
        Else
            ValidInteger = "You must enter a whole number"
        End If
    Else
        ValidInteger = "You must enter a number value"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Can there be more than one if, else, end if statement?

Comment: @user753143: I edited my post putting an example. The answer is yes, there can be as many as you need